# How to check if a user is member of a sharepoint group inside SPD's WD

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a workflow in SharePoint 2010 Workflow Designer and need to check if a user is member of a sharepoint list before I can continue the workflow.

How can I do this (without use of VS)?

I know there is a Impersonation Step, but inside that I can only check if a user is has some permission levels and that is not what I want.

I simply need to check if a user is member of a given sharepoint group. If yes I'll continue, else I'll cancel the workflow

Thanks for any help!

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a custom activity.

There's such an [activity on codeplex](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Is%20User%20a%20member%20of%20a%20SharePoint%20group&referringTitle=Home) built for SP2007 but I would think this is easily updated for SP2010. Its part of a [package](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com) that contains a variety of custom workflow activities.

This can be confirmed by looking at Microsoft's own [list of conditions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-conditions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376962.aspx?CTT=3) for SP2010.

Comment: Looking at the discussions about the 2007 package, it apparently can be installed into a 2010 environment without modification.