# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow - Modified by users existed in SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

Current we are working on the SharePoint designer 2010 workflow. Here we have the below issue.

Workflow need to satisfy a condition - "ModifiedBy user is existed in Specified SharePoint group" then do some action. We are unable verify this condition but we can verify with single user.

If any one do this before, please reply to this question.

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-member-of-a-sharepoint-group-inside-spds-wd

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to see it OOTB.

You can refer this link if you want this workflow action:

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com

[SOURCE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ae41ffb8-a01a-4787-92b1-dda8c9467636/check-if-user-belongs-to-specific-sharepoint-group-using-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)